# How to solve Matplotlib TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, jupyter

I am trying to print a graph xlabel with cifar-10 data label. 
However, I keep on getting this Type Error like below.

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow import keras

from tensorflow.keras.datasets.cifar10 import load_data

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

(x_train,y_train),(x_test,y_test)=tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

class_names = ['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer',
           'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']

x_train=x_train/255.0
x_test=x_test/255.0

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
for i in range(25):
    plt.subplot(5,5,i+1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(x_train[i], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.xlabel(class_names[x_train[i]])
plt.show()
```

It says the problem is with
     plt.xlabel(class_names[x_train[i]])
this line. 
Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple typo. You need to change the following line. With that change everything works as expected.

from

```
plt.xlabel(class_names[x_train[i]])
```

to

```
plt.xlabel(class_names[y_train[i][0]])
```

Full code is [here](https://github.com/jvishnuvardhan/Stackoverflow_Questions/blob/master/Cifar_plotting.ipynb) for your reference.